# Python. При использовании Keyboard нажимаются кнопки дважды

Tags: python, клавиатура, pyautogui

Я попытался сделать авто-кликер, но у меня появилась проблема: при включении проги, у меня почему-то заедают кнопки на клавиатуре, либо нажимаются несколько раз.
Вот код:

```
import pyautogui as pg

import keyboard

key = 'r'
key_2 = 'f'
pg.PAUSE=0.0001

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
        pg.click(button='right')
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key_2)
        pg.click(button='left')
```

Прошу помочь, ведь эта проблема очень мешает!

Comment: Цикл бесконечный и без задержек (разве что в `pg.click` будет задержка), вангую что пока вы нажмете какую-нибудь кнопку сработает несколько раз подряд. Добавьте sleep в цикл. А лучше, вместо ручной обработки, используйте хоткеи: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c1e4af724e46219f633367dd33e5542925f206b4/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/hotkey__hello_world.py#L15

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А не могли бы Вы прислать мне уже исправленный код? Просто я не совсем понимаю как это вставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо ручной обработки клика лучше использовать механизм хоткеев

Пример:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pg


pg.PAUSE = 0.0001

keyboard.add_hotkey('r', lambda: pg.click(button='right'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('f', lambda: pg.click(button='left'))

keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я решил проблему

`import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time

key = 'f'
key_2 = 'r'
key3 = 'h'
pg.PAUSE=0.0001

while True:
 if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
  pg.click(button='right')
 time.sleep(0.0001)
 if keyboard.is_pressed(key_2):
  pg.click(button='left')
 time.sleep(0.0001)
 if keyboard.is_pressed(key3):
  break`

Он стал работать как нужно!

Comment: @АртемШевелёв, пожалуйста, примите мой ответ, если помог

Comment: @АртемШевелёв, хорошо, что вы решили свою проблему, но мне кажется, это костыльное решение и лучше через хоткеи решать, если нужно поддержать выход из цикла, то в `keyboard.wait` есть параметр, хоткей, для выхода из ожидания: `keyboard.wait('h')`

Comment: ок! Спасибо большое!